# Converter doesn't seem to fire at all times on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, wpf-controls, datatrigger

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GroupColumnSummaryControl}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource c}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>.
```

Whats wrong with this code here. my convertor doesnt seem to fire when i do a mouse over. 
If i remove the convertor and assign the value as Red i can see the color.

this works perfectly fine

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GroupColumnSummaryControl}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red">
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
```

Comment: Post the code for the Converter.  And describe conditions when it does not fire.

Comment: The converter just returns solidredcolor brush. i have a console.writeline in the converter to check the firing.It just fires twice. once when the application loads and on first mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: (I used RichTextBox)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>            
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                    
              <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource colorConverter}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style> 
</Window.Resources>
```

This is the converter:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {      
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```